# Regex for extracting dosage form and size of drug label

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the texts `30` `tablets` and `5` `mg` from the following text using regex:

`"PACKAGE LABEL-PRINCIPAL DISPLAY PANEL NDC 63187-663-30 30 Tablets Levocetirizine Dihydrochloride Tablets 5 mg For oral administration Rx only 63187-663-30".`

The problem is the word tablets appears twice. How can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
(\d+) (Tablets|mg)
```

**SEE:** https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/1